# Show how much time the compiler spends on type inference

Tags: scala, sbt

I heard that type inference is one compiler phase that does take time, and that it is a good practice to add an explicit return type in some cases to speed up compilation.

Is there any means to display how much time the compiler spends on the type inference phase(s)? What I initially had in mind would be a tool that would show the cost of inferring specific return types (of methods, variables, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proxy solution is to use the `-Ystop-after:<phase>` private option with the `typer` compiler phase and time it. If you call it like (from `bash`):

```
time scalac -Ystop-after:typer MyClass.scala
```

you'll get a time result for all phases up to and including typer. You can experiment with this option, `Ystop-before:<phases>` , `Yskip:<phases>` and `Xshow:<phases>`, but the `Y` options are private and tend to be experimental and change/dissapear between `scalac` versions ( I used `2.10.0`). For example, I couldn't get `stop-before:typer` to work, to remove the time from the other phases. You can list them with:

```
scalac -Y
```